# Selecting value from related table in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE "Employer" (
        "employerID" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        "name" CHAR,
        "industry" CHAR,
        "contact1" CHAR,
        "contact2" CHAR,
        "email" CHAR,
        "website" CHAR,
        "facts" CHAR,
        "phone" VACHAR
        )

CREATE TABLE "Job" (
        "jobID" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        "employerID" INT,
        "title" CHAR,
        "description" CHAR,
        "type" CHAR,
        "salary" CHAR,
        "benefits" CHAR,
        "vacancies" INT,
        "closing" CHAR,
        "requirement" CHAR,
        "placement" BOOL,
        "applyTo" CHAR,
        "notes" CHAR,
        FOREIGN KEY (employerID) REFERENCES Employer(employerID)
        )
```

I am looking get values from database and set them to `JLabel` text, but I am not sure about the sql statement when `foreign` keys are involved. The SQL Statement should be to `SELECT` all values from `Job` table except `employerID` and use the foreign key `employerID` to obtain the `name` of a company...can anoyone show me the correct sql statement for this..i would like to display information like this example:

ANALYST - MICROSOFT

JobID: 4545454
Description: Good job
email: 123@hotmail.com
phone: 45545

but not sure how to display MICROSOFT

```
public void setText() {
    try {
    String sql = "SELECT a.*, b.name FROM Employer a INNER JOIN `Job` b ON a.employerID = b.employerID";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {

        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)); //how Do i Print the name value from Employer table?? 
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(4));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(5));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(6)); 
    }


}
```

How to print the `name` value from EMployer table as well as all data from Job table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple join might do the job.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*       // -- SELECT the columns you want to display
                       // -- eg b.Title
FROM    Employer a
        INNER JOIN `Job` b
            ON a.EmployerID = b.EmployerID
```

Comment: `a` is called the `ALIAS` of table `Employer` so intead of writing `Employer` you can just write `a`.

Comment: i am looking to add them to JLabel in java, eg `id.setText(rs.getString(1))` will that work ?

Comment: wouldnt the first FROM line include `JOB a` as opposed to `Employer a` in my case?

Comment: yes if the first column is the name of the column you want, otherwise you need trial and error to find the index of the column, by the way, what is the name of the column you are looking?

Comment: the same since it is using `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: i just to want to display all values from `Job` table and ONLY the `name` value from `Employer` table